# Should I add news about me in my linkedin profile?

Tags: linkedin

Recently, one my my work covered in some news websites. Should I add them to my linkedin profile. If the answer is yes, which section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you worked in a company that recently recieved positive media exposure, you should of course have it listed on your LinkedIn profile, under **Experience** and/or **Organizations**.

After you've added this, you will see some options for the entry. One of these is adding a relevant link, which in your case, could be a link to the article on the news websites. It looks something like this:

[image: Position details]

You can use the Link button to show something that you're particularly proud of from your time at the company in question.

Comment: I think I asked my question wrong. I made some individual project about my work field and it was published on news websites

Comment: @talis - That's fine. You were probably still affiliated with some organization (whether you were a student at a school, or working for a company), so you can still add it as a link to that position. If your work was completely independent, you can instead publish a post linking to your work. You can do this from the front page of LinkedIn, at the top of your news feed.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I actually published it but I want to make it visible for everyone in anytime. I think I'm gonna do the thing which you suggested first

Comment: well another question. Are my posts visible in my linkedin profile?

Comment: I actually don't know. I've never written one, so I don't know if it shows up directly on your profile. But I would agree with your decision to post is as a link to a position you held. That should make it visible.

Additionally, when you apply for a job in the future, you can specifically point out the existence of this article on your CV or in the application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Linkin is the Facebook of shameless self promotion. Write a post that links to the news story. Add self-promotional text to that post.

Comment: you could say just no

Comment: @talis - But the answer was yes. As far as I can tell, he wasn't being sarcastic.

Comment: @Alec I thought he was being sarcastic. So in which category should I put them?

Comment: @talis - I added my own answer, as it was a bit more substantial than I could fit into a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I was being a bit dry, but the answer is yes. When I do something like publish a blog at my company I knock up a quick linkin post to promote it. You can also attach links to job positions if you think it's a huge success.